# Using DES to encrypt and decrypt a file in Java

Tags: java, serialization, des

I'm trying to serialize an object (in this case a simple string), encrypt it, and write it to a file. The encryption seems to work, but the decryption always fails. I've tried searching around, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong..

```
// Create a new key to encrypt and decrypt the file
byte[] key = "password".getBytes();

// Get a cipher object in encrypt mode 
Cipher cipher = null;
try {
    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
} catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
    System.err.println("[CRITICAL] Incryption chiper error");
}

// Encrypt the file
try {
    new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test"), cipher)).writeObject("test text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("[CRITICAL] Error encrypting data: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Get a cipher object in decrypt mode
try {
    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
} catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
    System.err.println("[CRITICAL] Incryption chiper error");
}

// Decrypt the file
try {
    // This is the line that throws the exception
    System.out.println((String) new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream("test"), cipher)).readObject()); 
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("[CRITICAL] Error decrypting data: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Running the above code results in the following exception:

```
[CRITICAL] Error decrypting data: null
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2304)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3042)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2843)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1617)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1338)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at Server.DataPersistence.main(DataPersistence.java:203)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that nothing has been written to the file when you attempt to open and re-read the data back into your program.  Try calling `flush();` and then `close();` on the output stream before attempting to read the file back in again.

Comment: +1. In this case (a CipherStream), it needs to be `close()`. Otherwise the data will be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks! Calling `flush()` and then `close()` on the object outputStream did the trick! I assume it recursively closes all the other streams?

Comment: The streams in java follow the Decorator Pattern. Calls made on the outermost stream propagate down through the composed object structure stopping at each layer to do whatever that decorator might need to do for that call before ending up at the lowest layer.