# Not able to decrypt an encrypted file using DES in java from a different class

Tags: java, encryption, des

Basically, I'm able to create an encrypted file to store user's credentials. Now my requirement is to use that file for future reference to get the credentials by decrypting it and use it for verification of the user. I'm creating a windows based desktop application. I got few codes that decrypts successfully within the same class, but didn't get how to decrypt it from a different class.
Below is the identical code I used for encrypting. I got it from the net which ran successfully. Please tell me how to decrypt it now from a new class.

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
public class PrivateExample 
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String text=new String();
    text="This is an encryption test";
    byte[] plainText = text.getBytes("UTF8");
    System.out.println( "\nStart generating DES key" );
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    keyGen.init(56);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    System.out.println( "Finish generating DES key" );

    // get a DES cipher object and print the provider
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    System.out.println( "\n" + cipher.getProvider().getInfo() );
    //
   // encrypt using the key and the plaintext
    System.out.println( "\nStart encryption" );
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    System.out.println( "Finish encryption: " );
    System.out.println( new String(cipherText, "UTF8") );

   //Now writing to an ouput file the cipherText
   try{
       FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("c:/test.txt");
      fs.write(cipherText);
     }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
}
```

Comment: Your code above does not provide *any* kind of security. You may want to read into the subject before you start development.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt it with Cipher.doFinal() method after reading the textEncrypted from the file that you save. Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390526/using-des-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-file-in-java), Using DES to encrypt and decrypt a file in Java, this will help while working with files.

```
desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class, there is just one method. And that method generates a new random key each time you use it. The symmetric key needs to be the same for both encryption and decryption.